# having trouble with assignment compatibility?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

What i'm trying to do is use a single call to return a collection of 2 extensions of a base class.  Here's what i have:

```
public interface IView
{
   int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then i have a domain model that implements this interface

```
public class View: IView
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then i have a few classes that inherit from the base class

```
public class ViewA: View
{ 
   public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ViewB: View
{
   public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

from here i have a List that i'm trying to get to contain both:

```
var views = new List<IView>();
```

and create a view from my base since ViewA and ViewB both have Ids

```
var view = new View();
view.Id = 1;
```

now i'm trying to cast this to ViewA so i can set PropertyA like so:

```
var viewA = (ViewA)view;
```

but the debugger tells me i can't cast "view" to ViewA (this compiles just fine).

```
Unable to cast object of type 'View' to type 'ViewA'
```

I'm sure i'm missing something in my understanding of interface -> base class inheritance but i thought you could cast a "lesser" class to a "more defined" class this way.  reading about covariance, contravariance, and assignment compatibility, i would think i should be able to do this; apparently not though..

What i want to do is return a collection of both types of views (hence the List) so that i can cast them to the more defined views when i need them and leave them as base views when i only need the common properties.

I'd rather not have duplicated properties in ViewA and ViewB, is what i'm trying to do possible or do i just have this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm sure i'm missing something in my understanding of interface -> base class inheritance but i thought you could cast a "lesser" class to a "more defined" class this way. reading about covariance, contravariance, and assignment compatibility, i would think i should be able to do this; apparently not though..

You've got it backwards (I think). You can always cast an instance of a derived type to a base type, but not the other way around. If you cast an instance to a derived type, it must be an instance of that type at runtime.

It looks like what you're trying to do is somehow create an instance of `ViewA` from an instance of `View`. This isn't how casting works.

Here's an example that *would* work that might help. If you have your list of views:

```
var views = new List<IView>();
```

And you add an instance of `ViewA`:

```
views.Add(new ViewA());
```

Now, the compiler doesn't "know" that `views[0]` is a `ViewA`--it's a list of `IView`s after all. In this case you know more than the compiler and a cast is appropriate:

```
var viewA = (ViewA)views[0];
```

You also mention:

> I'd rather not have duplicated properties in ViewA and ViewB

Unless I'm missing something, you haven't duplicated any properties. `ViewA` and `ViewB` have different properties and inherit the `Id` property from the `View` class.

In other words, this looks fine:

```
var view = new ViewA();

view.Id = 4;
```

Comment: so then how would i get around the duplicating the id setting?  say i have this cast contained in a switch statement off of some property that tells me which cast to make so i don't have to set Id in both places.  is it possible to do this or am i just going to have to set Id in both places?

Comment: @JoshMeiburg: I just added a bit to the end of my answer. `Id` is inherited by `ViewA` and `ViewB` from the `View` class. You should not need to redefine this property in `ViewA` or `ViewB`.

Comment: what i'm having trouble with is i have the cast wrapped in 2 cases of a switch statement, since the view could be either ViewA or ViewB based on some criteria; however, i'm trying to avoid setting the Id property in both cases of the switch statement. that's what i mean by "I'd rather not have duplicated properties in ViewA and ViewB" (i gather that wasn't very clear).. it's more like i don't want to duplicate the Id property setting (and ofcourse many more).

Comment: @JoshMeiburg: Why not move the setting of the `Id` property out of the switch statement entirely? It will be available without a cast.

Comment: last question (i think), all this is working great now, so thank you very much! but, how can i reliably get the index of the item i just added?  since i need to cast this to a View first to set the base properties, then to the more specific ViewA to set the specific properties (as i mentioned, this is multiple cases in a switch statement in a loop).  I am currently using .Add and then getting the Count - 1, this assumes that the added item is the last in the collection.  Wouldn't .Insert(0, new ViewA()) be better since i'd always know it was index of 0? (allowing me to reference with views[0])

Comment: If you're using `List` like in your example, `.Add` [always adds the item to the end of the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) so doing `Count - 1` is fine. If you want something a bit briefer you could use LINQ's' `.Last()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Add instances of `ViewA` and `ViewB` to the list, instead of simply a `View`:

```
var views = new List<IView>();

var view = new ViewA();  // add an instance of viewA
views.Add(view);
```

You can access an item directly *(without casting, thanks Andrew)* to change the "Id" property on the base class, since the property is also defined in the interface:

```
var view = (View)views[0];
view.Id = 999;
```

Or test the type in order to access other more specific properties:

```
var viewB = views[0] as ViewB;  // first element is a ViewA, so viewB is null

if (viewB != null)
{
    viewB.PropertyB = "someValue";  // doesn't run because viewB is null
}

var viewA = views[0] as ViewA;

if (viewA != null)
{
    viewA.PropertyA = "someOtherValue";  // runs - you have an instance of viewA
}
```

Comment: The `Id` property is defined on the interface, so you should not need the cast to `View` in the second snippet

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot cast a "lesser" class to a "more defined" class.
But you can cast viewA and viewB to a list of View, so that when you can get the common properties.

Answer (score 0):

The type that you use to create an object is the type it shall always be - it never changes.

So you're creating your instance as:

```
var view = new View();
```

Because it inherits `IView` you can reference it as that or `View`, but it never changes from its type of `View`.

So when you try to cast it as `ViewA` it fails. It is never going to be `ViewA` unless you created it as such.

So if you do this:

```
var view = new ViewA();
```

Then it can be referenced as `IView`, `View`, or `ViewA`, but it will always be of type `ViewA`.